# Sources on mystical and spiritual meaning of Brit Milah?

Tags: product-recommendation, brit-milah, literature

What are some good sources discussing the mystical and spiritual meaning of Brit Milah as well as how it affects one's spirit/life/etc?

Comment: Maybe start [here](http://www.aspaklaria.info/002_BET/ברית.htm)

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel - How about an English version?  It sure LOOKS like there might be some good information on that page...

Comment: Could you please clarify your question. As it is, it is a rather vague.